# How do I create a Search page in Team Site?

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, search-results, content-search-web-part, team-sites

what is best way for me to create a search page in Team site.

I would like to add Refinement Web Part to search page and point out to tags used in the term store.

Answer (score 2):

If you want just a "results" page where the results are displayed or both a search page (where you enter the query) and a results page, you just have to create the page (or pages) and then add the necessary web parts. Getting them aligned and so forth requires choosing a page layout that contains the columns. (That is why I generally use an Enterprise Search Site Collection, all the work is done for you.)

The key after you create the page is to configure the web part settings so that the query is redirected back to the same page. The Results Web part simply reads the query string.